# How to scale a raphaeljs paper

Tags: raphael

I am using .svg files for thumbnails. The original .svg's came from CorelDraw, and they are about 400x400 each. But I wish to use them inside  75x75 thumbnail divs.

I have tried:

- one_thumb__paper.setViewBox( 0 , 0 , 75 , 75 , true ) ;
- one_thumb__set.transform( "s.5" )
- also, the [ScaleRaphaël](http://www.shapevent.com/scaleraphael/) class

Comment: Can you post a fiddle of it ?

Comment: see my answer for working fiddle

Answer (score 1):

I was doing two things wrong:

```
1 - 
//  the wrong way:
var my_set = my_paper.importSVG( my_svg_string); 5   

//  the correct way:
var my_set = my_paper.set();
my_paper.importSVG( my_svg_string , my_set );


2 - 
//  the wrong way:
my_set.transform( "s.5" )   

//  the correct way:
my_set.transform( "s.5,.5,0,0" )
```

---

see [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rYmNe/10/)

see [raphaeljs svg importer](https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import)